# Remapping a TFS project on a new computer

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

So I'm a total noob when it comes to TFS.  I've really only used Git previously on the Mac.  This is for work as I'm switching projects and I'm not sure how to get started.

This is what happened.  My computer got put on the network with its computer name.  I connected to our TFS server.  The person helping me get started last week created a Development folder on my c:\, and then mapped the folder structure in TFS to my local so I could view the project and do all that stuff.

Then IT didn't like that I installed the OS on my Mac partition myself and wanted to keep the images standard across machines.  So they reinstalled everything on my Mac/bootcamp partition.  When I connect to TFS now, on the top of one window, it says:

```
Local Path: C:\Projects\myWorkProject
```

Why does it say that since with this new install I have not mapped the project yet.  It seems to remember my old machine or workspace or something because when I look into my local path, none of the source code or any of that stuff is there which makes sense since I actually have not done any mapping on this new install.

So my question is, how do I map the project when TFS already thinks it's mapped?  Thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

TFS workspaces are unique to your user name and the remote computer name and workspace information is stored both on your local computer *and* on the server.

If you want to delete the existing workspace, or change the mappings, you can select the Workspace menu in Source Control Explorer, and select Workspaces... to open the Manage Workspaces dialog.

[image: Manage Workspaces]

Comment: we have done this but when we try and map a new workspace to the location used before vs2012 says its already mapped elsewhere.

Comment: You can also get to Manage Workspaces from the main VS menu: File.. Source Control.. Workspaces

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem and removing the workspace item worked. Also, I just wanna say, that as a user CVS, SVN, Git, and now TFS for a .NET project, It appears that Microsoft is going out of it's way to make something that is counter intuitive.

Comment: CVS, SVN and Git are more intuitive than TFS?

Comment: @Bomboca, well, i think Git is much easier to use, at least with software like sourcetree. TFS seems primitive compared to it. too much rigid.

Comment: It's rigid as to keep integrity and prevent non-senses (although still might have some) and so are the non-senses of git. Advantages and disadvantages on both sides. I will not fall into a discussion here.